# TextInputLayout leaves blank space when error is set to null

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I have a little problem with UI.

I'm using `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` to do a login, and set errors in an easy way.

Situation:

I have the `TextInputLayout` empty and there is no error to show.

[image]

Then when the user starts to write, I set `TextInputLayout.error = "Error Messge"`. Since here everything is correct.

[image]

But when user cleans the `TextInputLayout`, I clean the error setting it to null: `TextInputLayout.error = null`

[image]

And here is where the problem arrives. When the error is cleaned the space where the error was showed doesn't disappear. It leaves a blank space that I don't need.

Is there any way to remove it? I can't see any method to "clean" the error and remove this space.

P.S: Algo I tried to set to "blank" instead of null --> `TextInputLayout.error = ""`, but doesn't work.

Comment: after clear error setErrorEnabled(false) and when set error setErrorEnabled(true)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disable the error when removing the blank space. Then if you want to show the error message in future you need to enable it again.

Example:

```
if (exampleTextInput.editText?.text?.isEmpty()!!) {
    this.exampleTextInput.error = null
    exampleTextInput.isErrorEnabled = false
} else {
    exampleTextInput.isErrorEnabled = true
    this.exampleTextInput.error = "error message"
}
```